# mysql query not returning desired results

Tags: mysql, sql

I have three tables I am trying to pull results from but am turning up empty handed.  Here is my query:

```
SELECT f . *, o . *, u.username, COUNT (o.order_id) as cnt 
FROM products f, orders o, users u 
WHERE f.product_id=o.product_id 
AND f.user_id = u.id 
AND (f.title LIKE '%hlt%' OR f.description LIKE '%hlt%' OR u.username LIKE '%hlt%') 
LIMIT 5
```

this is returning no results although there is definitely records that meet this criteria (although apparently not as I have it written).

Comment: Without your table schema and sample data, not much help can be provided.

Answer (score 0):

You used `COUNT (o.order_id)` with out `group BY`.This is causing the problem.You can not execute this query with out using `GROUP BY`

[**GROUP BY**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html)

Answer (score 0):

You need to use joins when pulling data from multiple tables. Your query should be:

```
SELECT f . *, o . *, u.username, COUNT (o.order_id) as cnt 
FROM products f
JOIN orders o ON f.product_id=o.product_id
JOIN users u ON f.user_id = u.id 
WHERE (f.title LIKE '%hlt%' OR f.description LIKE '%hlt%' OR u.username LIKE '%hlt%') 
LIMIT 5
```